# How to get Tax Rates from Tax Class?

Tags: magento2, tax-class

I am working in a project where I need to fetch the tax rates which will be implement on products. But on product creation we assign Tax class. And I am not getting the relation between the Tax rates and Tax class.

Anyone who can exlpain the relation b/w rates and class? And how to fetch the tax-rate which will be applicable on the product.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?